# PHP testing array_walk result

Tags: php

I'm sure this is an easy solution - I <strike>wrote</strike> found this endswith function and thought I'd try the array_walk function instead of testing each string separately. I'd assumed that the result of the array_walk function would be false but it returns 1...How do I get it to test all the strings and return false if it didn't find a match? Thanks

```
class {    
    function endsWith($value,$key,$haystack)
    {
        $length = strlen($value);
        if ($length == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return (substr($haystack, -$length) === $value);    
    }

    function thing()
    {
        $email = "should@returnfalse.info";
        $arr = array("@test.net","@test.org.uk","@test.co.uk","@test.com");

        echo array_walk($arr,array($this,"endsWith"),$email);
    }
}
```

Comment: You get always true if array_walk was pass all elements; false - if array_walk not able to did

Comment: Try this: var_dump($arr); array_walk($arr,array($this,"endsWith"),$email); var_dump($arr);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) is not determined by whatever the callback does; it only informs you if walking the entire array was completed successfully.

You may want to look into a few alternatives.

This will return the number of matching elements and will also serve as a boolean test, but it will evaluate every element no matter what:

```
echo count(array_filter($arr,array($this,"endsWith")));
```

This will stop evaluating elements with `endsWith` as soon as a match is detected and will return `true` if there is a match, `false` otherwise:

```
$self = $this;
// cast to int because false is printed as the empty string
echo (int)array_reduce($arr, 
                       function($result, $v) use ($email, $self) {
                          return $result || $self->endsWith($v, null, $email);
                       }, 
                       false);
```

Comment: the array_reduce solution returns 0 even if there is a match (PHP 5.3), but I'm going to see if I can get it to work, it looks neat. Thanks

Comment: @JimSMith: I had misunderstood your intent here. The updated answer should work as is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class {    
    function thing()
    {
        $email = "should@returnfalse.info";
        $arr   = array("@test.net","@test.org.uk","@test.co.uk","@test.com");

        foreach ($arr as $domain) {
            $length = strlen($value);
            if ($length != 0) {
               if (substr($email, -$length) === $domain) { echo $domain; break; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_walk()` just iterates over the elements of an array and returns `true`, if it was able to do it. (`echo` casts boolea `true` to a string `'1'`) Have a look at `array_recude()`

```
$that = $this; // Cannot access $this directly before PHP 5.4
var_dump(
  array_reduce (
    $arr, 
    function($result, item) use ($email, $that) { return $result || $that->endsWith($item, null /* not used anyway */, $email);}, 
    false
  )
);
```

Additional `$key` is not used and useless in `endsWith()`.

Comment: thanks, this returned a  unexpected ')' error not sure what the problem is yet

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a function to all values and return a single result you should use `array_reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.3, you can use anonymous functions:

```
class {
    function thing()
    {
        $email = "should@returnfalse.info";
        $arr = array("@test.net","@test.org.uk","@test.co.uk","@test.com");
        $match = '';
        $found = false;
        array_walk($arr,function($value) use (&$match, &$found, $email) {
            $length = strlen($value);
            if ($length == 0) {
                $found = true;
                return;
            }

        if (substr($email, -$length) === $value) {
            $match = $value;
            $found = true;
        }
        });
        if ($found) {
            echo 'Found match: ' . $match;
        } else {
            echo 'No match found :(';
        }
    }
}
```